# Recieveing SMS via GSM modem in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, sms, at-command, sms-gateway

I am working on a project in which I have to send and recieve SMS via GSM modem in C# using AT commands. I am done with the sending part but having trouble reading sms from the sim card.
I have tried the following code and get the following response:
**OK
OK
ERROR.**
The code for reading the SMS is :-`

```
    public bool ReadSms()
    {



        //string buffer = string.Empty;
        if (this.serialPort.IsOpen == true)
        {
            try
            {
                this.serialPort.WriteLine("AT");
                 Thread.Sleep(2000);
                 this.serialPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + (char)(13)); 
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                this.serialPort.WriteLine("AT + CMGL = ALL" + (char)(26));
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                string a = this.serialPort.ReadExisting();
                MessageBox.Show(a);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Source);
            }
           return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }
    public void Opens()
    {
        if(this.serialPort.IsOpen == false)
        {
            this.serialPort.Open();
        }
    }
    public void Closes()
    {
        if (this.serialPort.IsOpen == true)
        {
            this.serialPort.Close();
        }
    }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

replace your this line "this.serialPort.WriteLine("AT + CMGL = ALL" + (char)(26));"

with this one   this.serialPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"" + (char)(13));

i hope you will not get the error.

Answer (score 0):

replace the line

```
this.serialPort.WriteLine("AT");
```

with

```
this.serialPort.WriteLine("AT" + (char)(13));
```

and change `26` to `13`